# in R: find observations with unique combinations across columns, regardless their order

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, combinations

I have a data frame with 1000 observations on 20 variables.

I want to select only the rows that have a unique combination across columns, regardless of their order.

That is, if a combination is `ABA` and another is `BAA`, I want the code only to return one of these combinations.

To identify unique combinations I run a simple `unique` command across multiple variables.

How would you write such a code?

Answer (score 2):

We can `sort` the data by row using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, then use `duplicated` to return the logical index, negate it and get the `unique` rows in the data.

```
dat[!duplicated(t(apply(dat, 1, sort))),]
```